# Arduino I would like to resolve the error

Tags: nodemcu, esp-12f

After compilation, it was confirmed that there were no problems. However, when uploading, this error message appears.

*esptool.py v3.0*

*Serial port COM4*

*Connecting....*

*Chip is ESP8266EX*

*Features: WiFi*

*Crystal is 26MHz*

*MAC: bc:dd:c2:5e:72:35*

*Uploading stub...*

*Running stub...*

*Stub running...*

*Configuring flash size...*

*A fatal esptool.py error occurred: Timed out waiting for packet header*

Comment: Not all errors happen in compilation time. I suggest you to debug, find the code where the bug might be happening and then post it, so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

That can mean that the compiler is having problems with the serial communication with the chip.

There can be gazillion reasons:

- silly things like the usb cable not being good enough - try different cables
- if you have many sensors attached the board may not be getting enough power - detach everything from the board first
- on some boards you also need to keep the "boot" button pressed while uploading the code.
- for some boards or if you are using an uploader usb "dongle" you also need to have correct drivers installed like FTDI, CH304x, SiLabs CP210x...
- the upload baud rate can be too high/low
- sadly some knockoff boards can simply be duds and don't work

I've experienced all these situations in some way or another, even on one really crap board I had to keep the "boot" button pressed then plug the board in the computer and keep the boot button pressed until the upload is finished.

Hop this gives you some ideas to try

Comment: My board doesn't have a boot button, it's a NodeMCU ESP-12F with only two buttons: RST and FLASH.

I also replaced the cable and uploaded by pressing the RST or FLASH button on the board when uploading, but the same symptom occurs.

Even though I put in the basic code that works, the same error occurred.